# Create a thumbnail of a video file in sdcard

Tags: android

I'm unable to create a thumbnail of a video file that i've place in the sdcard of emulator.
I'm getting the message:

`03-16 14:31:32.646: ERROR/MiniThumbFile(19847): Unable to create .thumbnails directory /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails and a null pointer exception.`

```
if (convertView == null) {
    iView = new ImageView(mContext);
    System.out.println("The path to the video" + filePath);
    Bitmap map = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
        getContentResolver(), position,
        MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
    System.out.println("map^^^^^^^" + map);

    iView.setImageBitmap(map);
    iView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(96, 96));
    iView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
} else {
}
return convertView;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one of the issues here (Although it would be better to see the complete method called), the one about the NullPointer is that although you are checking if `convertView` is null you don't do anything with it and then return the same convertView (Which is null when first called).

Given the name of the View (`convertView`) I assume that you are implementing the `getView(...)` method from an adapter. Returning a null object here will give you a `NullPointerException`.

To avoid this try doing this:

```
if (convertView == null) {
    iView = new ImageView(mContext);  
    iView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(96, 96));
    iView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
} else {
    iView = (ImageView) convertView;
}
Bitmap map = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
    getContentResolver(), position,
    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
iView.setImageBitmap(map);
return convertView = iView;
```

As for the other error it is hard to tell without more information.

Also, did you try this on a device?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to pablisco's answer and looking at the 'Unable to create .thumbnails directory' in particular:

Check you manifest has permission to write to external storage:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```